# How to add Requirements to Test Plan without closed Test Cases

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, microsoft-test-manager

Every time I add new Requirement suites to the Test Plan all closed Test Cases are added as well.

How can I exclude them from the Test Plan? If I manually remove them from the Plan then their links with the User Story is also deleted.

Comment: A requirement-based suite per definition contains all test cases associated with this requirement.

If you associate a requirement with a test case you say how to test if this requirement has been implemented correctly.

So why are some test cases closed in you case? What was your intention to close them?

Comment: Because many times the Requirements are changing, or their implementation differs from the way that testers have written their test cases. Especially on GUI applications. I know is not a good practice, but in real worlds that happens.

Comment: But then you could/should remove the association between the requirement and test cases in question since this requirement could not be tested by this tests anymore. It is the way it is supposed to be used, to my knowledge. Why do you want to keep the closed test cases associated with the requirement?

Comment: @Elena According to [MSDN - Test Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380712.aspx), when you close a Test Case with reason `Deffered` or `Duplicate` there is no need to remove it from the User Story. So, I would like to add the User Stories in the Test Plan without the closed test cases. If you agree with it, you can vote my idea in the User Voice (see my answer below) :).

Comment: I agree with you if it is about `Deffered` and `Duplicate`.
I've just voted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to exclude closed Test Cases from Requirement Suites. The only was is to deleted those test cases from the associated User Stories.

I added on User Voice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3359348-exclude-closed-test-cases-from-requirement-suites-